# High initial test validation score for Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, supervised-learning, stochastic-gradient-descent

From only the first epoch of training my NN with SGD (I use Xavier initialisation for weights), the accuracy shoots off to 92%, and then flattens out. The same thing happens with loss (but lower, of course). Is this a sign of overfitting, and if so: what can I do to decrease it?

Comment: no, high test set accuracy is not an indication of overfitting

Comment: Is your dataset imbalanced? How do the actual predictions look like?